# PhysicalPath Web Api .net 6 is null

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I am using RCL with Blazor Wasm and net 6-rc1

My images in the RCL (CommonComponents) project are in the wwwroot / lib / bootstrap-icons / icons folder.

In Net 5, all images are received from the Controller and web api with the following code:

```
var rootPath = _webHostEnverioment.WebRootFileProvider.GetDirectoryContents ("/ _ Content / CommonComponents"). FirstOrDefault (x => x.Name == "lib"). Physical path;
```

But when projects are updated from .net5 to .net6, PhysicalPath is empty
In version 6, webHostEnvironment. WebRootPath also returns null

Has access to folders and their contents changed in .NET 6?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with .NET 6. We can't guess what your code is doing or what its structure is. What you posted isn't actual code, so even that requires a guess

Comment: Could you please share your full code so that it can be reproducible.

Comment: I can confirm this issue.  Have you located a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. In .net 5.0 `WebRootFileProvider` is simple `PhysicalFileProvider`, but in .net 6.0 `CompositeFileProvider` is used with 2 providers under the hood: `ManifestStaticWebAssetFileProvider` and `PhysicalFileProvider`

`ManifestStaticWebAssetFileProvider` returns `null` for `PhysicalPath` property for directories. I could not google any info about `ManifestStaticWebAssetFileProvider` and why we need it. To revert old behavior you can do in startup class:

```
_webHostEnverioment.WebRootFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(_webHostEnverioment.WebRootPath);
```